# Binary file read and write in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, binaryfiles

I'd like to build a shiny app that will use the command line tool pdfimages on my shiny server to break a pdf into images.

To start this I need to read the pdf file and write it to a directory.  When I run the code outside of shiny it seems to work.  When I run it with shiny I get no error or warning message and it does not finish the execution.

```
library(shiny)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2) 


if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("file1", "Choose PDF File",
                  accept = ".pdf")
        ),
        tags$hr(),
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {
    observe({
      raw <- readBin(input$file1$datapath, what="raw")
      zz <- file("testbin", "wb")
      writeBin(raw, zz)
    })
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: Use [`observe`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observe.html) instead of `reactive`. Reactive expressions execute lazily - that is, only when an observer calls it. Since there's no observer here, the reactive expression will never execute. See the observe docs (under details) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: And btw once you change that, you'll probably run into other issues. `input$file1` is a data frame, where you access the paths of uploaded files like `input$file1$datapath`

Comment: I could probably get away with removing the line declaring fileSize and removing the "n =" argument in the line declaring raw.  If the fileInput brings back a data frame how would you access the raw binary info?

Comment: What I mean is, the path of the file is in `input$file1$datapath`, not `input$file1`. You'd just have to change those calls to read from the file path, not the data frame containing the file path.

Comment: I altered the app in the question to reflect what you mention but it does not seem to work. I get the warning, "Warning: Error in readBin: invalid connection"

Comment: `input$file1` will be null when the app starts. You can use [req](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/req.html) to check for this case and stop the observer.